# Why aren't there any fink binaries for 10.6 yet?

Tags: macos, fink

[Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) has been available for Mac OS X.6 for quite awhile, but only as source — there are no binary packages.  What is the obstruction in 10.6? How can someone help fix it?